# What is "Peripheral Dogma"?

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, terminology, definitions

The book, *[Introduction to Bioinformatics](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xYmcAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA6&ots=7fejD9SWmI&dq=peripheral%20dogma%20(bioinformatics)&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=peripheral%20dogma%20(bioinformatics)&f=false), by Arthur M. Lesk, 3rd edition; Oxford; low-price-edition*; in its chapter-1 (introduction), page-no. 6 ; provided a paragraph, entitled **"Dogmas: Central and Peripheral"**.

As-if; there exist a contrasting term for [central dogma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_dogma_of_molecular_biology).

But while thoroughly going through that paragraph (and other chapters linked(mentioned) in that-paragraph; I couldn't found the mention of the term "peripheral dogma" or such.

From the paragraph; it looks like the term "peripheral" has been used to indicate all information-flows other-than [genetic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code)s, and including Junk-DNA and  protein-folding-variations. No mention of epigenetic codes found.

In Web too; I could found only 1 [website](http://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/D464/%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AD%CE%BE%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82%20I.%20%CE%95%CE%BC%CE%AF%CF%81%CE%B7/0.intro.pdf)  used the term "peripheral dogma" in context with biology. which, too, does-not mention the definition clearly.

---

So, What is peripheral dogma?

---

P.S. this is purely a terminology question; which is looking for authoritative reference about usage of a term.

Comment: @Kiritee (user:25705) you made an answer which probably has been deleted; because that was just like a comment and as well id did not cited any reference. But if you know something about that; then you could of-course write that as comment. Whatever is your source (from-where you came to know about that... a class-lecture? a seminar? a magazine? whatever); you could mention as comment. Btw plz dont take any criticism by this website from heart. Strong criticism is a nature of this website and it does not criticize you personally. It only criticizes your statements and ideas.

Comment: No issues man. I am also sincerely waiting for someone to put some reference for this term. :)

Comment: @Kiritee since you once wrote an answer; I think you have gone through the term at some-or-some source and not via magic. What was that source? a book? a cheap competitive success magazine? a class-lecture? what book or what magazine? any photograph or screenshot of that source? could you improve details please?

Comment: I was only able to see only one reference for this [here](http://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/D464/%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AD%CE%BE%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82%20I.%20%CE%95%CE%BC%CE%AF%CF%81%CE%B7/0.intro.pdf) other than the book you had mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Kiritee but this is same as my second-source.

Comment: Exactly and honestly I had thought someone was questioning what this second dogma was all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author was just trying to make a point that while the "central dogma" is indeed key, there is more to it than that and that understanding of molecular biology has advanced beyond being simplified to that one tenet. Without having the passage in front of me, the ideas you gleaned from the paragraph make sense, though others such as epigenetics seem like they would fit as well.

As you've noticed, this term is difficult to find anywhere else, it isn't a standard term and therefore doesn't really have any meaning unless it is defined in the source. I wouldn't recommend using it yourself unless you plan to define it. The Wikipedia page for [central dogma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_dogma_of_molecular_biology#Transfers_of_information_not_explicitly_covered_in_the_theory) that you linked has a whole section on information transfer not included in the "central dogma" - I think you can safely assume the author was referring broadly to these items.

This all may be a bit of a joke, as well, given the definition of "dogma" and it's somewhat inappropriate use in the context of the central dogma of molecular biology - again, the Wikipedia article you linked talks about the problematic use of the word "dogma" in this scientific context.

Comment: Might be. But I suspect a bit; because [one](http://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/D464/%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AD%CE%BE%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82%20I.%20%CE%95%CE%BC%CE%AF%CF%81%CE%B7/0.intro.pdf) other source (and only one) quite boldly used that term ("peripheral dogma"). Seemingly, possibly I heard this term in seminars etc. (though very little part of these seminars I understand). May be all them doing the same mistake as me. I would wait, since 1 have 1 week bounty period; and on my experience at SE; drastically different answers may come from users. Thank you for response.

Comment: That second source seems to be using the term in a completely different way from the first you mentioned. In the first source, you referred to 'information flow' that is not contained in the genetic code. In the second source, they are talking only about protein folding and specifically mention that the folding is mostly due to the amino acid sequence: that fully fits under the "central dogma" because the information specifying amino acid sequence is the genetic code which is therefore also determining tertiary structure. Seems like evidence that the meaning of the term is not established.

Comment: (continued) In one source, "peripheral dogma" means other, secondary means of information flow that bypass "central dogma" - in the second source, "peripheral dogma" means the secondary consequences of the "central dogma."

Comment: the first source too; mentions about "protein folding" too many places on the same paragraph; so it seemed to me they've used it in similar or same sense. I've thought that already before asking the question.

Comment: Ok, but you also mentioned information flows that are not genetic codes - protein folding seems to be part of the genetic code (in most cases, at least; you can certainly have environmental influences on protein folding, or protein-protein interactions like prions). Without having the first source to consider, which is it?

Comment: couldn't understand what you're asking about. ("Without having the first source to consider, which is it?").

Comment: As well; I'm not 'claiming'; I'm just 'searching' and 'verifying' if there something called peripheral dogma. It is obviously possible there exist no-such terms; and both the users independently used that term  and in casual manner (not as any terminology).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity - I meant to ask: Is the first source talking about information flow that occurs outside the genetic code, or is it talking about information flow that happens as a consequence of the information in the genetic code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48949/discussion-between-always-confused-and-bryan-krause).

Comment: The first source (Book by Lesk, ed3) seemingly meant as if "information flow that happens as a *consequence* of the information in the genetic code". The author did not specified which one is central and which on is peripheral. (unlike the second, web-source). However on the book (Lesk) the section or paragraph could be divided into 2 parts. The first part describes about directly what we already know as central dogma. But the second portion deals mostly with protein folding, native-state, denaturation, encephalopathy etc. (the term prion was not found).

Comment: I'm sorry that my statement "the first source too; mentions about "protein folding" too many places on the same paragraph" is not factually accurate; it would be "on the same section the author dealt with different terms about protein folding". This error happened quite unknowingly; and when I wrote that comment; the book was not opened beside me.

Comment: May be it is an old and completely-obsolete term of the age when prions were in way to be discovered.